# How to prevent apk from overriding config files

Tags: configuration, upgrade, alpine-linux, apk-tools

So I've stumbled upon issue after issue every time I upgrade using `apk upgrade` that apk keeps on adding default config files without my consent, is there any way to have apk either never override/replace the config file or have it prompt the user the way apt on debian-based distro does?

Comment: Could you please share an example for such package(s), which config files were overridden? I'm not familiar with such apk option, but could also be related package specific install scripts (i.e. package bug)

Comment: Hi sorry, for late reply. The packages that has done that is nginx, php-fpm and rutorrent.


rutorrent will just override any config.php you have with the latest one


nginx will create it's own default folder and insert it's default (hello world conf) conf into it.


php-fpm will override the php.ini and php-fpm.conf

Answer (score 0):

If the [installation] is diskless mode (as I suppose), you can add the files you want to keep to lbu, with the command `lbu include /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`, for example.

In this way, when the OS restarts and reinstalls all the package with the default config files, at the end the overlay is untarred and you will get back the saved files.

.: Francesco

Comment: Thanks for the comment!
Well Alpine Linux is being run in a lxd container, so it's only when I decide to update it that it overrides my personal configurations

Comment: You update with "apk update && apk upgrade" ? If so, default behavior of apk is not overwrite the config files, rather it creates an .apk-new containing the default config file shipped with the package.